# Graphs connected, loops-free, and Multigraphs traversable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I would like to know if I'm right with these exercises.

**1. Which of the following graph are?**

[image]

**a. Connected:** 1st, 3rd

I'm discarding the 2nd because even there are two arcs that intersect, I read that this doesn't mean that there is a vertex in the intersection, so I'm assuming that the arc intersecting the triangle is not connected because I can't get from one of those vertices to one in the triangle. For the same reason and discarding the 4th. Let me know if I'm wrong.

**b. Free of Loops:** 1st, 2nd, 3rd

**c. Graphs:** 1st, 2nd

I'm discarding the 3rd and the 4th because they are multigraphs.

**2. Which of the multigraphs is traversable?**

[image]

The multigraph that are traversable are the 1st, 3rd and 4th.

Comment: Could you precise your definition of "traversable", it is not a standard one (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory_terms)

Comment: @PaulHudford The definition I have for that is that is a graph that can be drawn without lift the pencil from the paper and without going through the same arc twice, that is, if there is a path that contains all the vertices and that passes through each arc exactly once. I translate the term, so I don't know if is the correct one in english.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you are correct for **1a, 1b, 1c**. Note that for question **1c** we would rather say *simple graph* by opposition to *multigraph*. Indeed a multigraph is still a sort of graph.

I cannot say for sure for **2** as it lacks the definition of traversable. My guess would be that it means the graph has an Euler path : a trail that visits every edge exactly once (allowing for revisiting vertices). It is known that a connected graph has an Euler path if and only if the number of vertices with odd degree is exactly 2 or 0. Therefore your answer for question 2 would also be correct.

For question **1.a.**, if you want to understand why two edges may cross not at a vertex : There is a crucial difference between a graph and the drawing of a graph. A graph is defined whithout the use of drawing. It is a set of elements (called vertices), together with a set of pair of element (the edges). When looking at a drawing of a graph, you can move freely any vertex, or bend an edge as far as you want. The different drawings you will get will always represent the same graph. Lets look at your second example. We have a graph defined on 5 vertices, we can label them $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, and four edges $\{(12),(23),(31),(45)\}$.

[image]

This means that you can move the vertex around and get the following drawing :

[image]

This drawing is clearly of a disconnect graph. Therefore this will be the case for any drawing of this same graph, even if you put a more complex one such as :

[image]

This is the same graph. Different drawings but of same graph because the vertices and edges are the same.

For a given drawing, when two edges cross (not a a vertex), this is actually called a crossing. After that we can look at some related questions, mainly : For a given graph what is the smallest possible number of crossing in any drawing of this graph. If you can find one drawing with no crossing, then the graph is called **planar**. This is the case for instance of you second example. Even if the drawing you have shows one crossing, the second drawing I gave you is a drawing of the same graph but with no edges crossing. Therefore it is a planar graph.

**Edit** As explained in the comment, the four initial graphs are all planar, the fourth one can be drawn as

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Paul your answer was very helpful. I think the Eular path is the English term. When I translate it I got traversable, but yes that's the same definition.  So regarding the planar graph, the last one isn't a planar graph, right? Because has crossed. Just the second one is planar?

Comment: The four graphs are planar. For the last one in your drawing you have one crossing, but you can move the vertex at bottom right (the one that is into 2 loops/circles), this is the vertex giving you a crossing. you can move it around so that you will have no crossing. I'll edit my post to show it

Comment: I got those ones. I was asking for the one last one you show in the answer. The complex one.

Comment: Ok sorry. My "complex one" is the same graph than your second, the triangle plus an edge one the side : I just moved around the vertices and edges, but there is still the same vertices $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, and still the same edges $\{(12),(23),(13),(45)\}$. Therefore it is also planar. The drawing is more complex, but this is the same graph.